# Android: add badge to icons internal to my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to add badges to the icons in my android app. e.g. in the facebook app(for iPhone), in the home page the number of pending requests is shown on the requests icon.

Can someone provide any links/ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Had anything changed in 2016?do we have a library now?

Comment: Similar question with good answeres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/

Answer (score 20):

If you really want to do it. Use a `FrameLayout` which contains an `ImageView` with your icon and a `TextView` with a ninepatch drawable as background in the right corner. Add margins to the `ImageView` if you want the badge to be a bit outside the icon.

Comment: @alexanderblom - http://alexanderblom.se/gmail-unread-count/ is not working now.. can you please provide a new one.. in fact I wanted this functionality to implement on TabHost

Answer (score 8):

Thanks Alexanderblom ,for the hints.i used that logic and manage to create badge on a internal imageicon.here is the xml file.and you have to just create a red circle on the drawable.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="2sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and the circle.xml is

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/Red" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

Android doesn't support badges on icons.

Instead, it provides the notification system (icons in the notification bar, etc), as well as the ability to create [widgets](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) that can be added to the users "desktop".

Answer (score 3):

check this library which adds badge to the icon/button/tab

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, is good for Sony, Samsung, LG, HTC, Xiaomi, ASUS, ADW, APEX and NOVA Launchers.

https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Answer (score 0):

Follow below define steps for add notification count to app icon

Steps:

1. Add mavenCentral to your build script.

   repositories { mavenCentral() }
2. Add dependencies in your app gradle.

   dependencies { 
   compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
   or 
   compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3@aar' 
   }
3. Add the codes below for display notification count on app icon:

   int badgeCount = 1; 
   ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount); //for 1.1.4 
               Or
   ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(badgeCount); //for 1.1.3
4. If you want to remove the badge

   ShortcutBadger.removeCount(context); //for 1.1.4 ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).remove(); //for 1.1.3
                Or
   ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, 0); //for 1.1.4 ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(0); //for 1.1.3