# can we show badge number on android app icon like iphone?

Tags: android, badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

I just wanted to know that can we show the badge number in Android app Icon?

I know that android notifications are different then Iphone but i want to do in my android app.

Is that applicable?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: [Look at a Question over here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8476544/593709)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think we can do it. check this question [Badge on Android TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292679/badge-on-android-tabhost). the accepted answers refers to this code https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

**Edit** i haven't tried yet. check this question. [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

Comment: Does this project let put badge on app icon?

Comment: +1 for suggestions... and is @Jin35 asking, it will posible?

Comment: @Jin35 This lib saves my life, and it works with app icon, as in facebook app
https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: try this...this will work...i tried and is working fine... https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Answer (score 7):

You can do it only by creating widget instead app icon. Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610384/android-add-badge-to-icons-internal-to-my-app) for more info.

Comment: What is with the mail shortcut? It shows a badge and isn't a widget.