# App-Icon Create an Overlayinformation (Number)?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, notifyicon

How can I clone this behaviour (iOS) on an Android-App?

[image]

Technically its definitly possible as I have an app by my own on my Androidphone - its an Email-App with a very similiar indicator on the Icon. (shows the number of unread Emails)

Comment: Check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937700/can-we-show-badge-number-on-android-app-icon-like-iphone .. Hope it may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to doing this on the home screen, that is an [app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

yes you can implement overlay like ios.. by the way it is called badge value.

[here is one sample available on github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

You just have to add classes in your project and call below lines

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

hope it helps.

Comment: the first thing is: regarding to screens it's only in an app possible with that method, not outside - on the icon itself; and second thing is, I work with mono, so I couldn't use the library anyway.. but thx anyway +1 for effort ;)