# How to display unread count to the android app icon?

Tags: android

I want to display the unread count to the application icon. I refer the lots of stack overflow answers for achieving that. All the links are saying that it is not possible. But android Mail, Message application displays the unread count at the top of the icon and in some links says that use widget instead of icons. But I don't know how to use the widget instead of icon displays in android application.

[image]

Like the above image I want to display unread count in my application icon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

Comment: This solution works in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24804467/957954

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't do that on application icon. Android doesn't allow that.

But you can do that using widget.
There are many question related this, check it first.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937700/can-we-show-badge-number-on-android-app-icon-like-iphone)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610384/android-add-badge-to-icons-internal-to-my-app)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

[Widget Example](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/)

[Widget Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

**Update : 24/04/2015**

Now this is possible for some launcher app.

Check this [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) and [BadgeUtils](https://gist.github.com/Tadas44/cdae2f5995f21bf1c27f)

**Update**

Android allow [Modify a Notification Badge](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges) from Android 8.0 (PI level 26).

Comment: Thanks for your response.. yes I already refer these answers.But my requirement is how to using widget instead of application icon..Any sample coding is there????

Comment: [look here for widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: Yes i know how to create widgets..but i want to know how to use widgets instead of application icons(How to display widgets instead of displaying app icon)

Comment: Ok.But in some application(facebook,message,Gmail) displays count in application icon itself..These application icon is in app drawer screen.

Comment: @Android_kalai yes you are right, all application developed on system os expect facebook. may be system os given some authority to facebook for that.. In this days facebook is also unbuild app for new devices..

Comment: Ok..thanks for ur suggestions..Really forward to some more updates about my requirement

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Tadas44/cdae2f5995f21bf1c27f    \n https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: @CapDroid I think android should provide this functionality in its new release. In some demos on github it is done using reflection technique. And some says it is not supported in Android L, I don`t have L but i have tested this in kitkat it works fine.

Comment: Why some apps can use ? like Telegram,whatsapp.. ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Showing Badge in application icon is not allowed by default in Android. We can do this in some of the customized devices available in android:
   Below are the links how we can show on some Device like Sony,Samsung etc.

https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Utility Class I found on git:- will be helpful also

https://gist.github.com/Tadas44/cdae2f5995f21bf1c27f

2. And for rest of the Non customized devices we can create a custom widget to reflect this same behaviour.

See How to create Widget:
https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/