# How to show unread count on app icon android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing an android application in which i have to show the number of unread count on the application icon. Please provide if any way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285155/how-to-display-unread-count-to-the-android-app-icon?rq=1

Comment: @Pang Thanx for replying...is there any other way dat instead if widget we have any other option

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Android for this. A few device manufacturers and home screen makers offer this, though I am not aware that any have a documented and supported API for it.