# How to show notification count on app icon like Facebook?

Tags: android, android-widget, badge, android-icons

I want to show unread notification count on my app icon when app is not opened.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285155/how-to-display-unread-count-to-the-android-app-icon?rq=1) post seems to be close but it is **3 years old**. Has there been any change on this or I should go with solutions provided in the accepted answer?

[image: notification icon]

Comment: first you should store noftifications in local local storage(shared preference or db) and pass to viewbadger. when user open the app you should be delete noftifications and clear viewbadger. follow this example of code stackoverflow. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: nothing close ui widgets... this is only question... on stack overflow tag.... :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Unfortunately you cant achieve this for all android devices.**

Certain manufacturers (e.g. Samsung or Sony) have included this functionality into their customised Android launchers. Also some 3rd-party launchers (e.g. Nova Launcher) have included an API to accomplish this.

*Some related posts for more information:*

- [How does Facebook add badge numbers on app icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205569/does-samsung-modifies-its-android-roms-to-have-badges-on-email-and-sms-icons?rq=1
- [adding notification badge on app icon in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086189/adding-notification-badge-on-app-icon-in-android?rq=1)
- [How to interface with the BadgeProvider on Samsung phones to add a count to the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136483/how-do-you-interface-with-badgeprovider-on-samsung-phones-to-add-a-count-to-the?rq=1)
- [How to add a notification badge/count to application icon on Sony Xperia devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices?rq=1)
- [How to make application badge on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713226/how-to-make-application-badge-on-android?rq=1)
- [How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

*And some libraries that might be helpful:*

- [Samsung badger](https://github.com/shafty023/SamsungBadger)
- [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)
- [Badges](https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Badges)

*and more...*

Comment: OM$G I can't believe Android have not created a native way to do it

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution But it work in some devices like samsung , Huawei..

Like ADD Library

```
implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar"
```

ADD to Gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Finally Add this in MainActivity.java file for Check

```
    int badgeCount = 16;
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, badgeCount); //for 1.1.4+
```

> 16 Notification will be visible on app icon

And this is it !!

For detail Click here

[ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter can be used library:
[Flutter App Badger](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger)