# In Notification Badge icon not showing in Vivo,oppo custom OS but in Samsung showing in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

In **Flutter** android i implemented Notification and that works for all devices. but I'm getting problem in **Badge icon** count when multiple notifications arrives. That needs to show count on icon, in my Samsung device its works like charm but in vivo, oppo, Mi that badge count is not showing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you showing Badge ? As far as i know there is no Support from android for this .

Comment: Check the notification settings for this particular app, the app icon badge migh have been disabled

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary i check for that device but there is no option for that like in samsung.

Comment: @ADM as we see in whatsapp badge icon total count unread message that type not showing in vivo.in samsung work in my app .

Comment: That&#39;s not a Android api . It&#39;s probably a 3rd party library which does not work on all devices. Also you need to provide the code with question ..

Comment: @SachinSuthar please provide code snipt so that some one can help you :)

Comment: @ParthPitroda ok

Comment: @ADM please check now quetion with code

Answer (score 1):

give it try:-

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger
>
> [How to show notification count on app icon like Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374002/how-to-show-notification-count-on-app-icon-like-facebook)
>
> [How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)
>
> https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger